# Why $∆U=Q_v$ only at isochoric condition for real gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

U is a state function.So, ∆U should be same if we carry out an isochoric process from state A to State B or through any other process for real gas. And as ∆U=Qv for real gas in isochoric process, so,∆U=nCv∆T. Taking system from state A to B by any process, let's say P, ∆U should be same. Then, Can't I write it again as ∆U=nCv∆T=q+W. Am I missing Something?

Comment: It thermodynamic equilibrium states A and B are the same (i.e., the temperature and volume of states A and B are the same), then any process P between states A and B has the same change in internal energy.  This has nothing to do with whether we are dealing with a real gas or an ideal gas.  I guess I don't understand your question.

Comment: You are aware that Cv is a function of V and T, right?  It is a function of T only for an ideal gas.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I asked the question because I want to understand it in physical sense so that it help me in imagining the situation in my mind. Regarding partial differential proof, I can do that

Answer (score -1):

The internal energy of a single phase gas U is a function of temperature T and volume V.  $$U=U(T,V)$$In the limit of large volume, the gas approaches ideal gas behavior, and the internal energy approaches the ideal gas limit that is a function of temperature only:  $$Limit\ [U(T,V)_{V\rightarrow\infty}]=U^{IG}(T)$$The heat capacity at constant volume of a gas is defined as $$nC_v(T,F)=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V$$The heat capacity of a real gas in the ideal gas limit of large volume is $$nC_V^{IG}(T)=\frac{dU^{IG}}{dT}$$